Ubuntu 18 not booting on USB
I want to be able to dual boot Ubuntu 24 and Ubuntu 18 because I want the newest version, for personal use, and I have software that runs on Ubuntu 18. I was running Ubuntu 20 so I fresh installed Ubuntu 24 from a USB drive and all went well. For reference, all I did was download the ISO file from the Ubuntu page, use Startup Disk Creator, and rebooted. From here, I had booted from the USB and installed Ubuntu 24.
However, now I am trying to do the same thing with Ubuntu 18 and it is not working. I did the same thing as I did for 24: Downloaded the ISO, used the Startup Disk Creator and rebooted. However, this time it did not boot from the USB and took me straight into my already installed Ubuntu 24.
I have looked at many questions like this and don't see how any of these could impact me. I made sure the ISO file was not corrupted by using SHA256. I put Ubuntu 24 back on the USB drive and it tried to boot from there again, which worked so I don't think its the USB drive. I tried to boot Ubuntu 18 from a different USB drive, which didn't work. My hardware is not that old but I tried using the Minimal CD, which didn't work.
The fact that installing Ubuntu 24 was seamless leads me to believe that it is something having to do with the Ubuntu 18 download I got. Having checked that against the SHA256 seems to imply that it is something in the Ubuntu 18 ISO file itself and not a result of a corrupted ISO file or faulty download.
Any help would be much appreciated. If you need more details I will be happy to provide them the best I can.
